# Shell Script - Read a file and add line if certain text does not exists

Tags: bash, shell

Update: Appreciate everyone's input. I believe there's a bit of confusion going with what I am trying to achieve. I've address these questions in the edits below.

**Original Question:**

I'm a noob when it comes to shell scripting and try to do my best to come up with my own. The following code has gone several iterations to come to this point.

I am sorry if this has been answered by i was not able to get this working to my needs, hence the reason for the question.

Scenario:
IP Phone provisioning server.
A folder contains multiples, of which majority are .cfg files. 
Of these, if the filename starts with 001565 or 805ec0 add line with "sip.listen_port". Ignore everything else.

Issue:
I am able to do above without any issues. However shortcoming that if the file already have this line, my script adds another line.

Expected outcome:
What i would like to do is, read the file, see if the text exists and only then add the line. This is where I've failed.

Any help to point me to the correct direction would be appreciated greatly.

Current Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#check old yealink phones are there
if ls 001565* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    LOOP=0
    FILES=001565*
else
    LOOP=1
    FILES=805ec0*
fi

while [ $LOOP -lt 2 ]; do
    for f in $FILES
    do
        while read -r line; do
            if [[ "$line" =~ "sip.listen_port*" ]]; then                
                UNAME=$(awk '/user_name/{print $NF}' "$f")
                # take action on each file. $f store current file name
                # check the lenght of extension number and set the 
                if [ ${#UNAME} -lt 2 ]; then
                    echo "sip.listen_port = 900$UNAME" >> $f
                elif [ ${#UNAME} -lt 3 ]; then
                    echo "sip.listen_port = 90$UNAME" >> $f
                elif [ ${#UNAME} -lt 4 ]; then
                    echo "sip.listen_port = 9$UNAME" >> $f
                else
                    UNAME=${UNAME:(-3)}
                    echo "sip.listen_port = 9$UNAME" >> $f
                fi
            fi
        done < "$f"

    done
    #check new yealink phones are there
    if ls 805ec0* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
        FILES=805ec0*
        LOOP=$((LOOP+1))
    else
        LOOP=$((LOOP+2))
    fi
done
```

---

**Edit 1:**
To ease off the confusion, let me add a picture showcasing what files are inside a typical folder, and the contents of a typical file.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boFEq.png)

Typical file contents:

```
#!version:1.0.0.1
## the file header "#!version:1.0.0.1" can not be edited or deleted. ##

account.1.auth_name = 105
account.1.display_name = 105
account.1.enable = 1
account.1.label = 105
account.1.password = 
account.1.sip_server.1.address = pbx.dns.name
account.1.sip_server.2.address = 
account.1.user_name = 105

auto_provision.server.url = http://provisioning.url/
```

What is working:
The script will check the current folder each file starting with 001565 or 805ec0 and adds the following line.

```
sip.listen_port = 9XXX
```

What I was trying to achieve is that, if the above line exists, no modifications should be done to the file.

Hope this helps to clarify any issues.

Comment: could you post an input/output or something like before/after. I just didn't get what do you want...I'm almost sure script you have made too complicated for your task, it could be much much easier

Comment: @KonstantinVustin, I've updated the question with more information. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to read all the lines with `while ... done < "$f"`. You can use simple `grep` instead:

```
for ...  
    if ! grep -q '^[[:blank:]]*sip\.listen_port' "$f"; then 
        ...
        ...
        echo "sip.listen_port = something" >> "$f"
    fi
done
```

---

If you **insist** on using `while`, you can try this:

```
for ...
    found=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        [[ $line =~ ^[[:blank:]]*"sip.listen_port" ]] && { found=1; break;}
    done < "$f"

    if ! ((found)); then
        ...
        ...
        echo "sip.listen_port = something" >> "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I just tested and the grep method worked for me really well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I have the feeling that if your file contains the "sip.listen_port" it adds an extra line, but if the line is not present, then it is not added. I'm right? If it is the case, then you simply have the conditional reversed:

```
if [[ ! ("$line" =~ "sip.listen_port*") ]]; then
```

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary. Also, what this does is simply checking if the line contains somewhere the **literal** string `sip.listen_port*`. You can try it for `line='foosip.listen_port*bar'`. This line will match the regex, whereas `line='sip.listen_port = something'` won't (but should, judging from the question).

Comment: Yes, I just assumed his conditional was working according to his needs. But he stated that he want to exclude the files that contain the literal string `sip.listen_port`, so the star should be removed. Parenthesis are for clarity.

Comment: In any case, there are shorter, cleaner and easier ways to accomplish that duty. I just tried to help with the current code.

Comment: The `*` won't be removed. It's literal. The line has to contain it.

Comment: That's not what the poster said, and that's not what we can see in the `echo` commands that write that string. It is only in the conditional, and it is not needed, IMHO.

Comment: Heh, I meant that if you use the regex as you have it now, the line would need to contain literal `*` in order to be matched :) Which is most likely not what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, right, I agree with you. I kept that because the OP said it was working with his data, just on the wrong file.

Comment: *However shortcoming that if the file already have this line, my script adds another line.* In other words, the regex/code doesn't work for OP :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. To clarify, what I am trying to achieve is the if the line exists, it needs to ignore. Only to add if the specified line doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks everyone, managed to get this fixed using the grep method mentioned earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
$ ll                      
total 4,0K
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd  0 июл 16 10:03 001565tmp.2rbFa0rT3G
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd  0 июл 16 10:03 001565tmp.6o5BywVcLF
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd  0 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.220Jgcmv0e
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd  0 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.7EGpvDw71e
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.F78rxzUBCz
$ cat *
sip.listen_port = something # only file 805ec0tmp.F78rxzUBCz has this entry
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES_DIR=<your_path>
for filename in `ls $FILES_DIR | grep -E "^(001565|805ec0)"`
do
  if grep -q '^sip\.listen_port = something' $filename
  then
    continue
  else
    echo "sip.listen_port = something" >> $filename
  fi
done
```

Result:

```
$ ll
total 20K
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 001565tmp.2rbFa0rT3G
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 001565tmp.6o5BywVcLF
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.220Jgcmv0e
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.7EGpvDw71e
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 10:03 805ec0tmp.F78rxzUBCz

$ cat *       
sip.listen_port = something
sip.listen_port = something
sip.listen_port = something
sip.listen_port = something
sip.listen_port = something
```

P.S: I didn't get the logic around UNAME...and your output doesn't explain what this var is, so i decided it will be "something"

**UPD:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES_DIR="<your_path>"

for filename in `ls $FILES_DIR | grep -E "^(001565|805ec0)"`
do
  if grep -qE '^sip.listen_port = [0-9]+' $filename
  then
    continue
  else
    uname=`awk '/^account.1.user_name = [0-9]+/ {print $3}' $filename`
    echo "sip.listen_port = 9$uname" >> $filename
  fi
done
```

**Before:**

```
$ ll
total 16K
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 26 июл 16 16:36 001565tmp.2rbFa0rT3G
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 53 июл 16 16:36 001565tmp.6o5BywVcLF
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 28 июл 16 16:35 805ec0tmp.5ai0gFOkas
-rw------- 1 vkd vkd 25 июл 16 16:35 805ec0tmp.F78rxzUBCz

$ cat 001565tmp.2rbFa0rT3G 
account.1.user_name = 105

$ cat 001565tmp.6o5BywVcLF 
account.1.user_name = 21516
sip.listen_port = 921516

$ cat 805ec0tmp*          
account.1.user_name = 12345
account.1.user_name = 18
```

**After:**

```
$ cat 001565tmp.*
account.1.user_name = 105
sip.listen_port = 9105
account.1.user_name = 21516
sip.listen_port = 921516

$ cat 805ec0tmp.*
account.1.user_name = 12345
sip.listen_port = 912345
account.1.user_name = 18
sip.listen_port = 918
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin,

The UNAME value is derived from "account.1.user_name = 105". The numeric value at the end. It can be any length from 2 digits to 5 or more.

So the logic is to get 9XXX value as "something" depending on the length of the username.

Hope this explains the logic.
Asanka